# Are circuit board power sockets easily interchangeable?

Tags: pcb, power-connector

Newbie question I'm afraid :/ I have a device with an unusual sized power jack (5.5 x 3.3) making it difficult to work with for my project. To switch this out can I simply remove the current socket and solder a slightly differently sized one (capable of accepting the same voltage) in its place or are there any other gotchas I should consider?

I've been looking at the various power socket components and they all seem to share the same 3 prong underside arrangement as my current power socket- can it really be that simple (assuming my soldering skills hold up)?

[image: Power socket]

Comment: They are quite often an absolute b**** to desolder without wrecking the PCB though.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/132503/35022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're likely to be the same, but it's not *guaranteed*, so check with a continuity tester first. The unsoldering is likely to be the tricky bit, larger components are harder. Is this really easier than making up a cable with the correct plug on?

Comment: Thanks- TBH it probably would be easier for someone who knows that they're doing to make a cable with the correct plug but I've never done anything like that and am trying to avoid having to worry about connecting individual wires if possible. I just assumed switching out a component would be simpler but see now even that might be fiddly also.

Comment: Difficulty of this is like a 2 out of 10. Difficulty of making an adapter cable is like 2.5 out of 10.

Comment: Thanks guys- I think you're right. If I can just study up on how to wire what I need to to this cable it should simplify the whole project.